# How to order individuals within groups where group order must remain the same

Tags: r, permutation

I am attempting to get every ordered combination of individuals in groups while keeping the order of the groups consistent.

For example, there are four individuals in group 1, two individuals in group 2, and two individuals in group 3. The group size might change and the number of groups might change in different iterations. But the groups must always stay in the correct order (1,2,3) but I would like to know how individuals within the group could be arranged. In this case, I think there should be 16 combinations where someone from group 1 is first.

In R, the groups are set up as:

```
data.frame(letters[1:8],c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3))
```

Some possible outcomes could include:
`a,e,g` or `a,f,g` or `d,e,h`.

But shouldn't include outcomes like:
`h,a,e` and `e,g,c`.

I thought this would be a permutation without replacement problem, but nothing I've searched so far considers groups. I attempted to combine individual and group into a single unique identifier, get all possible combinations, and just search the results for those that contain the group parts of the identifier in the correct order, but the results become unwieldy really quickly as individual or group size increases.

Any insights into how I might structure a function to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Are there not just 4*2*2 possible permutations? (Choose 1 of the 4 in group A, 1 of the 2 in group B, and 1 of the 2 in group C) So the total number of possible permutations is just the product of the group sizes? Are you asking specifically about how to generate a list of these 16 permutations? It seems like nested for loops would be a simple way to program it. (Questions focusing on programming are off-topic on Cross Validated, so this will probably be closed if there isn't a statistics/probability question buried inside.)

Comment: If the numbers of groups and group sizes can change, then how are we to interpret the process of "arranging" individuals within groups?  Indeed, how can the concept of a "group" possibly survive such changes??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another commenter has noted, this is question is probably off-topic for Cross Validated, but this should get you what you need.

```
data.frame(chars=letters[1:8], levels=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3)) |>
    pivot_wider(values_from=chars, values_fn=list, names_from=levels) |>
    lapply(unlist) |>
    expand.grid()
```

Outputs

```
   1 2 3
1  a e g
2  b e g
3  c e g
4  d e g
5  a f g
6  b f g
7  c f g
8  d f g
9  a e h
10 b e h
11 c e h
12 d e h
13 a f h
14 b f h
15 c f h
16 d f h
```

Note that you'll need to install the `tidyr` package for `pivot_wider`.